# NodeJS copyFile then unlink in callback

Tags: node.js, fs

I have a large amount of files (millions) that I want to copy from a folder to an other one, but then based on some parsing options, I will need to delete the file if it doesn't respect some criteria.

I'm doing the parsing on my local copy of the file because it would be slower on the network to parse (read file + parse) than doing it locally.

My code looks like this :

```
for (let file of files) {
    fs.copyFile(from, to, err => {
        if (err) return;
        parse(file);
   });
}
```

The `parse` function is something like :

```
parse = file => {
    fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
        //do some parsing
        if (notOk) {
            fs.unlink(file);
        };
    }
}
```

The problem is that it's doing all the `copyFile` and doesn't seem to execute the callback with the `unlink`, and I really need to unlink as soon as the file is finished copying since I can't afford the disk space to copy all files first.

Do I need to use the `Sync` version of those methods or something else?

Thanks

I would have expected an output like this :

```
copyFile a
copyFile b
copyFile c
parsing a
copyFile d
unlink a
parsing b
copyFile e
...
```

but instead I have all `copyFile` and none of the parsing/unlink happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `files` contains millions of files, you're starting millions of concurrent copy actions, which is probably overwhelming your system.

Instead, consider using something like [`async.eachLimit`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit) to limit the number of concurrent copy actions.

Untested example:

```
const async = require('async');

async.eachLimit(files, 10, (file, callback) => {
  fs.copyFile(from, to, err => {
    if (err) return callback(); // or pass `err`
    parse(file, callback);
  });
});

function parse(file, callback) {
  fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
    //do some parsing
    if (notOk) {
      fs.unlink(file, callback);
    } else {
      return callback();
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: RAM is not an issue and the system is not freezing, I want to get this as fast as possible since it is dealing with Tb of data, limiting does not seems like a solution in my case

Comment: Copying files doesn't require RAM, it requires I/O bandwidth.

Comment: Sorry I was talking about stacking up the copyFile commands - which I guess are queued in memory inside the node process. The I/O should be the limit and I want the system to be at 100% (or near 100%) while executing the program

Comment: @HRK44 the result of that will be that all copy actions will contend for I/O, and it may take quite a while before they finish and call the callback in which you subsequently parse the file. Try your code with a limited number of files (say 10 to 100) first.

Comment: I've tried it with a smaller amount on a dev environment (<100) and still got the same result with the callback being called after the copies.

Comment: So the callback isn't being called at all? Are you also logging something in case of errors (instead of just returning)? Does it work with even a single file?

Comment: Yes the callbacks are called after all the copyFiles are done

Comment: Again, this all points to I/O contention. When you start multiple copy actions, each one will compete with the others (file I/O isn't a first-come-first-serve kind of concept), with the result that they will all finish at about the same time (especially if the files are of similar size).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening, the callback in the coping is finishing so the thread is finished, but the functions can not finish, you can make this sync and is going to work fine and be more clear, but other way is to transform the functions to promises so you can return the promise and wait for them.

You could write something like this.

```
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs'); 
const files = ['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt', '4.txt'];
//promisify all the fs functions to use.
const copyFilePromise = util.promisify(fs.copyFile); 
const readFilePromise = util.promisify(fs.readFile); 
const unlinkPromise = util.promisify(fs.unlink);

//make a parser function that return a promise.
const parse = (file) => {
    return readFilePromise(file) 
            .then(() => { 
                //do some parsing 
                if(notOk) 
                    return unlinkPromise(file)
    });
};

//store all the promises in an array
let promises = []

//iterate for all the files using the promisify aproach of the functions
for (let file of files){
    //add all the promises to an array of promises.
    promises.push(copyFilePromise(from, to).then(parse(file)).catch(console.error));
}

//wait for all the promises to resolve.
Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: I tried the promise approach but I'm still facing the same issue, could you maybe elaborate a bit more on your code?

Comment: I change the code to make it more understandable and push all the promises in an array and a final line to wait for all the promises to resolve, it do not control errors, and is just and example for the aproach I think you need to folow.